# How to use User Ids in Firebase analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, firebase

We have been using firebase for months now. But we started putting user_id via setUserId() in android application as follow:

```
firebaseAnalytics.setUserId(viewModel.userInfo.id)
```

I can see these user-ids being set in bigquery table. So, it is working perfectly fine. For now, we have done this on testing devices only so, this field is set for 5-10 users only, as of now (visible in bigquery table).

Now, when I try to create audience via 'user Id' in firebase analytics, it is showing some random numbers for users based on 'user id'

[image]

Also, it shows 0 results for the exact user id which i can see in big query table. Screenshot is as follow:

[image]

Can you please tell me what is the problem with firebase or if i am doing something wrong. I can see right user_id in bigquery table.